# Multiplication of rank 3 tensors to give another rank 3 tensor of the same dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

I have two rank three tensors, X and Y of the same dimensions, say n x n x n. I wish to do the equivalent of matrix multiplication on these two tensors. So with regular matrix multiplication, if I multiply two n x n matrices I get another n x n matrix in return. Is there a way to do this with tensors? Clearly I can split my tensors into n sets of n x n matrices and then do matrix multiplication on these to get n new n x n matrices. However this doesn't feel right because I can choosing one specific direction which gets priority over the others.

Note that I am not looking for the tensor product not the inner product of two tensors.

Thanks!

Comment: Matrix multiplication can be understood as putting two rank-2 tensors $A_i^j$ and $B_i^j$ together to get a rank-4 tensor $A_i^j B_k^l$, then "collapsing" along a shared dimension to get $(AB)_i^j = A_i^k B_k^j$, a rank-2 tensor. Is this the kind of multiplication you are considering?

Comment: What you are looking for is some form of [tensor contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction). There is no way of doing this for rank $3$ tensors that is "common" in the way that matrix multiplication is for rank $2$ tensors